# Ravendb: order by date descending index

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

I am trying to create an index that will allow me to retrieve the top n items in descending date order.

There seems to be no option to sort an index by the date?

I need to be able to query using the index with a `Take(n)` clause to get the last `n` items.

```
public class ConcernStateByDateIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ConcernState>
{
    public ConcernStateByDateIndex()
    {
        this.Map = concerns => from concern in concerns
                               select concern.EntryDate;
        this.Sort(_ => _.EntryDate, SortOptions.?????)
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides just the sort, which synhershko answered below, your index map should be an anonymous object containing the values you want to index, not just a single value.

Answer (score 5):

You never sort in an index, you use queries to sort results when querying an index. The Sort option in an index is required to tell RavenDB if the field is numberic so sort from queries will work.

Sorting in queries looks something like this:

```
session.Query<ConcernState>().OrderByDescending(x => x.EntryDate);
```